# Python3.6 - cannot import name '_imaging' [Django 2.1.2, Apache 2, CentOS 7]

Tags: python, django, apache, centos, python-imaging-library

I'm running my Django application with Apache on CentOS. I already (pip) installed `Pillow` on my virtualenv(python3.6). When I run `python` in shell, `from PIL import _imaging` doesn't generate any error. However, When I put this line of code inside the Django application, it generates an error: `cannot import name '_imaging'`. This is confusing.

I set the python path: `/var/www/ProjectName/virtualenv/bin/python3.6/site-packages` (in WSGIDaemonProcess), and the error occurred in the same location, so I think it's not an issue that Django is running on another python version.

Maybe is a mod_wsgi error? I installed mod_wsgi with `yum install python35u-mod_wsgi`

Can anyone help me with this issue? Thanks a lot.

Comment: Have you tried `from PIL import _imaging as P_img` ??

Comment: I just tried it. It works fine in the shell, but if I add this line in the django project, it pops up the same error :(

Answer (score 0):

this is really a stupid mistake.

As I suggested in the question, the `mod_wsgi` I'm using is for `python3.5`.

Solved by uninstalling `python35u-mod_wsgi` and installing `python36u-mod_wsgi`.